# How do I get the latest version of winetricks on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, updates, wine, winetricks

I have installed `Wine` and I am quite happy with my current version but `winetricks` has let me down a few times with various error messages.

How do I update `winetricks` to get the very latest version on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The version of `winetricks` that comes with the stock Ubuntu installation is often quite old. It is a great idea and a very safe one to update `winetricks` manually, *independent* of your main `Wine` installation, this can be done in a few simple steps:

**1. Check for the latest version, remove the old version:**

First check to see what is *the latest version* available from upstream with this handy one-liner:

```
curl --silent --show-error \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks --stderr - \
| grep ^WINETRICKS_VERSION | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Then if this trumps your own installed version (to see *your* version run `winetricks --version` from a command line) remove your currently installed version:

```
sudo apt-get remove winetricks
```

**2. Install the latest version:**

Then download and install the very latest version:

```
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin
```

As demonstrated on my own system the latest version can then be tested:

```
andrew@ilium~$ winetricks --version
20240105-next - sha256sum: c43ad4a2529441656e3f5a0b5ed6e248de15bf5cf657510ec2c0f6efc2562080
andrew@ilium~$
```

**3. Add some extras & check for newer syntax:**

It may also be a good idea to ensure that you have a few required 'helper' applications for `winetricks` to run, although most of these *should* have already been installed with your copy of Wine:

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract p7zip unrar unzip wget zenity
```

Then check the correct usage, which could have changed from your older version:

```
andrew@ilium~$ winetricks -h
Usage: /usr/local/bin/winetricks [options] [command|verb|path-to-verb] ...
Executes given verbs.  Each verb installs an application or changes a setting.

Options:
    --country=CC      Set country code to CC and don't detect your IP address
-f, --force           Don't check whether packages were already installed
    --gui             Show gui diagnostics even when driven by commandline
    --gui=OPT         Set OPT to kdialog or zenity to override GUI engine
    --isolate         Install each app or game in its own bottle (WINEPREFIX)
    --self-update     Update this application to the last version
    --update-rollback Rollback the last self update
-k, --keep_isos       Cache isos (allows later installation without disc)
    --no-clean        Don't delete temp directories (useful during debugging)
    --optin           Opt in to reporting which verbs you use to the Winetricks maintainers
    --optout          Opt out of reporting which verbs you use to the Winetricks maintainers
-q, --unattended      Don't ask any questions, just install automatically
-r, --ddrescue        Retry hard when caching scratched discs
-t  --torify          Run downloads under torify, if available
    --verify          Run (automated) GUI tests for verbs, if available
-v, --verbose         Echo all commands as they are executed
-h, --help            Display this message and exit
-V, --version         Display version and exit

Commands:
list                  list categories
list-all              list all categories and their verbs
apps list             list verbs in category 'applications'
benchmarks list       list verbs in category 'benchmarks'
dlls list             list verbs in category 'dlls'
fonts list            list verbs in category 'fonts'
settings list         list verbs in category 'settings'
list-cached           list cached-and-ready-to-install verbs
list-download         list verbs which download automatically
list-manual-download  list verbs which download with some help from the user
list-installed        list already-installed verbs
arch=32|64            create wineprefix with 32 or 64 bit, this option must be
                      given before prefix=foobar and will not work in case of
                      the default wineprefix.
prefix=foobar         select WINEPREFIX=/home/andrew/.local/share/wineprefixes/foobar
annihilate            Delete ALL DATA AND APPLICATIONS INSIDE THIS WINEPREFIX
andrew@ilium~$
```

**4. Safely reverse these steps:**

If for some reason you wish to return to your older repository version you can simply run the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/winetricks
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

And all will be as it was.

**Notes:**

- [WineHQ Wiki: winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) All the best winetricks info from the WineHQ Wiki.
- **Semi-Automation**: It is now possible to *partially* automate the update process by running `sudo winetricks --self-update` and if not happy with the results roll this back with: `sudo winetricks --update-rollback`.

Comment: Use `sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/bin` instead?

Comment: Traditionally the place for user compiled or packaged files has been `/usr/local/bin` or even `~/bin` but certainly `/usr/bin` will work.

Comment: `sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin` will move winetricks to /usr/local and name it bin if /usr/local/bin doesn't exist. I needed to do `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` first.

Comment: @jhasse Now I could be very wrong but I have always though that a defualt installation of Ubuntu included the creation of /usr/local/bin? Otherwise yes, I can see the problem....

Comment: a 3 years newer `winetricks` indeed (August 2017 insteadt of August 2014) ! → this advice is still great and valid.

Comment: @FrankNocke I come back every now and then to ensure it is still a valid answer for a modern Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 7):

## Updated 2019 answer

The winetricks versions that are available in Disco and Eoan are able to update themselves [[1]](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/1257#issuecomment-506794071).
If you happen to be using 19.04 or later, just run:

```
sudo apt install winetricks
sudo winetricks --self-update
```

If you're on an older version of Ubuntu, you can fetch the .deb package here:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/all/winetricks/download