# Winetricks: Can't locate and install d3dcompiler_43.dll?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have a game running on Lutris and I need to install **d3dcompiler_43.dll** library. However, when I try installing it trough *Winetricks*, the package is simply not on the list.

The only similar package (with a similar name) I see is d3dcompiler_47.dll, however, the game doesn't run with this one. My Wine version is 3.18. I am pretty sure the package used to be there, but I don't remember what wine version I used. Do you know how to install it without *Winetricks*? Or if I should I use another wine version instead in order to install it?

Comment: Hi. What's the name of the game? Have You searched WineHQ for that? Maybe You could use Play on Linux? At the end, that's the possible way of installing dll files I've found: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/wine/57825-install-dlls-wine.html . Let me know if it works - I could post it as the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself the most recent version of Winetricks [as demonstrated here..](https://askubuntu.com/a/755060/57576) After you have done this you will see the required version as I demonstrate below:

```
andrew@ilium~$ winetricks list-all | grep d3dcompiler
d3dcompiler_43           MS d3dcompiler_43.dll (Microsoft, 2010) [downloadable]
d3dcompiler_47           MS d3dcompiler_47.dll (Microsoft, FIXME) [downloadable]
andrew@ilium~$
```

And then hopefully all will be well!

Comment: That's it. Turns out I didn't have winetricks package installed at all on my system, but rather used Lutris's build in winetricks version. However this one was apparently really old and that was the problem. All I needed was installing a (newer) winetricks from the apt and now it works like charm. Thanks!

Comment: @VladSkurtolov Great news!