# Can't install DLLs in Winetricks

Tags: software-installation, wine, winetricks

I'm trying to install TodoList app as from terminal and by using GUI.
http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=linux

It throws an error:

```
Note: command wine /home/pdd/.cache/winetricks/comctl32/cc32inst.exe /T:C:windowsTemp_comctl32 /c returned status 193. Aborting.
```

Comment: This is **not** a solution to your specific problem, but there are [all sorts](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-excellent-todo-list-apps-for-linux-that-you-might-not-have-heard-of/) of ToDo applications meant for Linux. If you don't get a resolution, those may be of interest to you.

Comment: I wonder if you have the latest winetricks? This can be seen by running `winetricks --version` and the latest version is '20200412-next'. If you have older version have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/q/755059/57576

Comment: @andrew.46 thank you! How I can mark your answer as best?

Comment: @KGIII I will try

Comment: @PDD This solved the issue? I have not given an answer as such but if the issue is solved for you I can write one up :)

Comment: @andrew.46 yes. Please write your answer -- I will choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases of error messages with winetricks an update to the very latest version of winetricks will fix the issue; the repository winetricks is almost always at least slightly aged!

To test this I followed this excellent question and answer on Ask Ubuntu to update to *the very latest* winetricks:

[How do I get the latest version of winetricks on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/755059/57576)

Note that at the time of writing this answer this should give you the following version:

```
andrew@ithaca:~$ winetricks --version
20200412-next - sha256sum: 9ce444892e885bf7318b1f6c251dafb7a43fc26bb3078215f630e8a2b3f15874
```

Now the following command should be successful in installing the *prerequisites* and required dlls for TodoList, and certainly it worked well on my Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 system:

```
winetricks --verbose comctl32 mfc42 vcrun6
```

And hopefully on yours as well :)