# Presonus Studio One installing with wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to install Presonus Studio One on AV Linux. Here is the tutorial I am trying to follow.

1. Install Winetricks
2. Type Winetricks in Terminal; the following screenshot should pop up.

[image: Instructions#1]

3. Select Install and application and click OK on the bottom right.
   The following screenshot should pop up:

[image: Instructions#3]

Select cancel in the bottom right.

4. Select Install a font and click MS Corefonts.

[image: Instructions#4]

5. Click ok in the bottom right. The following screenshot will appear:

[image: Instructions#5]

This is where I think I am hitting my snag. Finally, the tutorial says to Install a DLL. Here is the following screenshot:

[image: Instructions#6]
But Here, I get an error message and I don't know how to fix it:
[[image: Checksum Error6]
Hopefully after this error is fixed everything will work. Wine installed the program without any hiccups, but I can't open it. Again, Here is the inside of the .desktop file, it may provide a clue: [image: Insides of Studio One] Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: Let them know that their instructions are inaccurate.

Comment: You awarded the bounty. It is still useful if you provide feedback, for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

You could try the following:

1. Update to the latest version of `winetricks`.
2. Rename the file as instructed in the message.
3. Try installing again.

This has been successful for many people.
Sources:

1. [Can't install DLLs in Winetricks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267887/cant-install-dlls-in-winetricks)
2. [winetricks sha1sum mismatch rename and try again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749549/winetricks-sha1sum-mismatch-rename-and-try-again)

### 1. Updating `winetricks`

You can get your current version with

```
$ winetricks --version
```

and which is the latest available with

```
$ curl --silent --show-error https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks --stderr - | grep ^WINETRICKS_VERSION | cut -d '=' -f 2
20210206-next
```

If you don't have the latest, update and check with

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
$ chmod +x winetricks 
$ sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin
$ winetricks --version
```

[or](https://askubuntu.com/a/1196637/226614)

```
$ sudo winetricks --self-update
$ winetricks --version
```

Source: [How do I get the latest version of winetricks on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755059/how-do-i-get-the-latest-version-of-winetricks-on-ubuntu)

### 2. Renaming the target file

```
$ mv -v <filename> <filename>.bak
```

### 3. Installing again

Repeat the procedure.

**Related**:

1. https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-wine-with-winetricks